# Networking and access

Tags: networking, home-networking, port

I do not know all the networking terminology so I'll try to explain what I want to do.

I would like to bridge my neighbor in to my network wirelessly using CPE's, but I do not want them to have full access. I basically want to bridge them in and give them access to only a specific IP and port so they are not using my internet or gaining access to any other items on my network.

Should I create a different network all together and only allow a certain route between the 2 networks? If so, can only one point me to the answer on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the easiest and most secure way of doing this is to create a separate network (subnet) for them and to put a firewall device between that subnet and the rest of your network which limits connections to just a single IP address.

Most consumer routers cannot do this type of setup out of the box. I would look either for a router which can run OpenWRT/LEDE or pfSense. Ideally this would be a router with several different interfaces so the subnets can be physically separate or with support for VLANs and tagging. Answering exactly how to do this is really not possible until you have a specific router/platform picked.